# How to choose which CMake executable target will be the default one?

Tags: build, cmake

I have written a `CMakeLists.txt` file including 2 executables (`target1` and `target2`):

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(target1 ${CXX_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(target1 ${requiredlibs})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(target2 ${CXX_FILES} ${OTHER_CXX_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(target2 ${requiredlibs})
```

Now every time when I run make without any parameters both targets are rebuilt. But I want to define `target1` as default executable so that running make without any parameters only builds `target1`. For building `target2` I would run `make target2`.

Is this possible?

In the Makefile created by CMake there is the following definition:
default_target: all

I think I need a way to set this `default_target` to `target1`.

Another problem I have is that make always rebuilds the targets, even if no source file has been changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An example CMakeLists.txt that does what you requested:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(target1 a.c)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(target2 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL b.c)
```

For me it does not rebuild the target if the source files are not changed (or modification time did not change). Output I get:

```
$ make -f Makefile 
Scanning dependencies of target target1
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/target1.dir/a.c.o
Linking C executable target1
[100%] Built target target1
[$ make -f Makefile 
[100%] Built target target1
```

Note that the second make does not rebuild anything.

(you could read the [CMake manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html) for this type of information)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and for your example. EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL solved my problem.